# Can someone explain the negative sign in the equation?

Tags: integration

F is the driving force of the system

and U is the quasi-potential based on integration.

$$U^{\text{int}}_{AB}(x)=U^{\text{int}}(x_B)-U^{\text{int}}(x_A)=\int_{x_A}^{x_B}\boldsymbol{F}(x)dx$$

$$\boldsymbol{F}(x)\sim -\frac{\mathrm{dU^{\text{int}}} }{\mathrm{d} x}$$

I can't understand in the above equation, why a negative sign appears.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Thank you @cineel

Comment: Are you sure that your first equation is correct? Pretty sure it's $\int^{x_B}_{x_A}F(x)\,dx=U(x_A)-U(x_B)$ (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Work_and_potential_energy) does support this)

Comment: Thanks @Kyky from the wiki I found the line "It is tradition to define this function with a negative sign so that positive work is a reduction in the potential,"